# Compare datagridview1 and datagridview2 and mark same values c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem with comparing datagridviews. I need to compare 2 datagridviews and if values are same, mark them or do something. (I import values from excel)

I cant use linq it's slow.

I try this but it seems I cant get it to work:

```
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < grv.Rows.Count; currentRow++)
{
   var rowToCompare = grv.Rows[currentRow]; // Get row to compare against other rows

   // Iterate through all rows 
   //
   foreach (var row in grv.Rows)
   {  
       if (rowToCompare.equals(row) continue; // If row is the same row being compared, skip.

       bool duplicateRow = true;

       // Compare the value of all cells
       //
       for (int cellIndex; cellIndex < row.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
       {
          if (!rowToCompare.Cells[cellIndex].Value.equals(row.Cells[cellIndex].Value))
          {
             duplicateRow = false;
             break;
          }
       }

       if (duplicateRow)
       {
           grv.Rows.Remove(row);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should not remove a row from your gridview while iterating through it

Comment: Is there any other way how can i do that ?

Comment: can u give me example how can i do it... im quite new to c# :)

Comment: i get data from excel

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string pot = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + textbox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection pove = new OleDbConnection(pot);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textbox_sheet.Text + "$]", pove);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt); /* napaka | oldedb driver ? :O*/
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: not to remove... I have 2 datagrids and i need to compare values in both. if same i need to show them somewhere or mark them.

Comment: i dont know why but i get error at row1.cells and row2.cells

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: It should work now. And please comment on my answer, not your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable src1 = grv1.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataTable src2 = grv2.DataSource as DataTable;
    int index1 = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row1 in src1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in src2.Rows)
        {
            int index2 = 0;
            bool duplicateRow = true;
            for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row1.ItemArray.Count(); cellIndex++)
            {
                if (!row1.ItemArray[cellIndex].ToString().Equals(row2.ItemArray[cellIndex].ToString()))
                {
                    duplicateRow = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (duplicateRow)
            {
                grv1.Rows[index1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                grv2.Rows[index2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            index2++;
        }
        index1++;
    }
}
```

This should color duplicates in red. Be sure that both gridview have the same cell number.

Comment: I thinks it's because of the way you bind your datas. To solve this problem, I iterate on the source. I tried this code and it works : when clicking on button1, the duplicates become red.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. foreach (DataRow row1 in src1.Rows)

Comment: Did you bind your datas in the gridview before calling this code? This exception happens because your datagridview has no rows.

Comment: Can you see some data in your datagridview before running my code?

Comment: public void NaloziDTW1()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string pot = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + textbox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection pove = new OleDbConnection(pot);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textbox_sheet.Text + "$]", pove);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt); /* napaka | oldedb driver ? :O*/
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
          } i inport excel file.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this code? Just put some data in both your gridviews, add a button to your form and link it with my onclick method. It worked for me so it should work for you

Comment: lol im such an idiot sometimes :D i saw what i did wrong :D but now i get error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable src1 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataTable src2 = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
        for (int i = 0; i < src1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row1 = src1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            var row2 = src2.Rows[i].ItemArray;

            for (int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

This will highlight the cells which have the same values. Provided both the datagridviews should have same number of rows.