# Bind to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can i bind data to datagridview?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string pot = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + textbox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
OleDbConnection pove = new OleDbConnection(pot);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textbox_sheet.Text + "$]", pove);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
myDataAdapter.Fill(dt); /* napaka | oldedb driver ? :O*/
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? How many rows are in the datatable. In my experience, even if the table is empty, the column headers will load. Do you get those?

Comment: Can you share what fixed it? Someone is going to come behind us with the same issue, and will not know what to do. Post your answer and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end:-

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in web application you have to add `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`.

Else tell us what is the problem in your above code? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Which platform you are using? Web or Windows? I think its windows as per the error message, so no need of DataBind(). Only if you assign the source is enough which you are already doing. So what is the problem in your code?

Comment: I see i dont need to bind in windows form. i need this to work and thhe guy said that i need to bind data to datagrid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255274/compare-datagridview1-and-datagridview2-and-mark-same-values-c-sharp

Comment: I din't get what is the problem you are facing and what is your question

Comment: guy said "Did you bind your datas in the gridview before calling this code? This exception happens because your datagridview has no rows" And i dont know how can i do that.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? If there is no record, your grid will be empty and it won't throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below MSDN link. It has working examples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fbk67b6z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not mention it, this question was tagged as winforms. Winforms does not need  
      `dataGridView1.DataBind();`

You have not given us any errors or hints as to where it fails. I suspect it is in the formation of this connection string or select statement. The code to bind the datatable to the DGV is correct

```
string pot = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + textbox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
OleDbConnection pove = new OleDbConnection(pot);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textbox_sheet.Text + "$]", pove);
```